# speed up python code

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

EDIT 2: Additional information based on the comments:
The function is supposed to compute the radial integration of an image (i.e. in polar coords) and then normalize by the radius.  I.e., in Mathematica notation: rotmean = Integrate[ f[r] r, {r,0,rmax}] / Integrate[ r, {r,0,rmax}].  In practice I want to do bilinear interpolation when I flatten the image from a 2-D pixel map to a 1-D radial average. If I do not interpolate, and just use the nearest neighbour, the values out close to zero radius can be quite off.

So the algorithm can be described as follows:

- Compute the radius mesh
- Find the floor of the radius as matrix index
- Find the remainder from the floor for the bilinear interpolation of the pixels

Now, for the vectorize solution given at the bottom, I do some pre-computation:

- Find the image weighted by the bilinear interpolants (the 0 and +1 pixel are mage_p and mage_n respectively.  This gives the radial sum (rather than average) Integrate[ f[r] r, {r,0,rmax}]
- The hard step conceptually (for me) to vectorize the problem was to collapse the N**2 pixel image into a N*sqrt(2) radial sum.  That's done with the lines such as "rmean[rfloor] = mage_p", noting that rfloor are both of length N**2 whereas rmean is of length N*sqrt(2)
- Also compute the weights, which gives Integrate[ r, {r,0,rmax}]
- Convert from radial sum to average.

ORIGINAL POST:
I am trying to port a function from Matlab to Python (based on WinPython x64 2.7.6.4) and I am struggling with how sluggish it is. The code is designed to take the rotational average of an image around the center. Typically the application would be to find the rotational average the power spectrum of an image, but it can be used for image-space as well.  Here is the code:

```
def rotmean( mage ):
# This is terrifyingly slow
t0 = time.time()

N = int( np.floor( mage.shape[0]/2.0 ) )
M = int( np.floor( mage.shape[1]/2.0 ) )

rmax = np.ceil( np.sqrt( N**2 + M**2 ) ) + 1

rmean = np.zeros( [rmax] )
weights = np.zeros( [rmax] )

[xmesh, ymesh] = np.meshgrid( range(-N, N), range(-M, M) )
rmesh = np.sqrt( xmesh**2 + ymesh**2 )
rfloor = np.floor( rmesh )

remain = rmesh - rfloor
# Make rfloor into an index look-up table
rfloor = rfloor.astype(np.int)

t1 = time.time()
# It takes 300 ms just to get to here in the function.  
print "Init time = " + str(t1-t0)
print "Max rfloor = " + str( rfloor.max() )
print "rmean.shape = " + str( rmean.shape )


# Certainly mage*(1-remain) can be precalculated as well if we want to use more memory

for I in rfloor:
    # Sum pixels
    rmean[rfloor[I]] += mage[I]*(1-remain[I])
    rmean[rfloor[I]+1] += mage[I]*remain[I]

    # Calculate the total area of each pixel so we can compute the average from the sum
    weights[rfloor[I]] += (1-remain[I])
    weights[rfloor[I]+1] += remain[I]

t4 = time.time()
print "Total loop time = " + str(t4 - t1)

rmean /= weights # compute average from sum
raxis = range(0,rmean.size)
return [rmean, raxis]
```

It is difficult to get past how slow the function is compared to Matlab. It takes about 450 ms in Matlab to execute on my laptop, whereas it takes Python 300 ms just to get to the for loop, and about 180 s to execute for a 2k x 2k image on my much more powerful desktop. I realize that Matlab uses JIT to compile for loops, but I tried compiling the code into Cython to accelerate the for loop and it's actually slower than the interpreted code. I suspect that I am not understanding something about how Python allocates memory or such but I cannot find anything of note with profiling.  As far as I can tell from the limited documentation available, I am doing in-line (in-place) operations here by use of the += operator?

Vectorization via numpy would seem to be an obvious solution but I cannot see how to vectorize the operation.

EDIT: Ok, I vectorized the code and it is within spitting distance now, about 0.5 s in Python (although the desktop computer has a vastly more powerful CPU, Xeon versus i5). I tried a number of ways to improve the speed of the for loops but the best I was able to do was over 30 seconds.

```
t0 = time.time()

N = int( np.floor( mage.shape[0]/2.0 ) )
M = int( np.floor( mage.shape[1]/2.0 ) )

rmax = np.ceil( np.sqrt( N**2 + M**2 ) ) + 1

[xmesh, ymesh] = np.meshgrid( range(-N, N), range(-M, M) )
rmesh = np.sqrt( xmesh**2 + ymesh**2 )
rfloor = np.floor( rmesh )

remain = rmesh - rfloor
# Make rfloor into an index look-up table
rfloor = rfloor.astype(np.int)

# I can flatten remain and mage
mage = mage.ravel()
remain = remain.ravel()
# remain_n = np.ones( remain.shape ) - remain;
remain_n = 1.0 - remain;
rfloor = rfloor.ravel()
mage_p = mage*remain
mage_n = mage*remain_n

# Somewhat better initialization time (~200 ms) but still slow...
t2 = time.time()
print "Initialize time = " + str(t2-t0)

rmean = np.zeros( [rmax] )
rmean_n = np.zeros( [rmax] )
weights = np.zeros( [rmax] )
weights_n = np.zeros( [rmax] )

# Find positive remainders
rmean[rfloor] = mage_p
weights[rfloor] = remain

# Add one to indexing array and add negative remainders to sum
rfloor += 1
rmean_n[rfloor] += mage_n
weights_n[rfloor] += remain_n

# sum
rmean += rmean_n
weights += weights_n
# and normalize sum to average
rmean /= weights

raxis = range(0,rmean.size)
t1 = time.time()
print "Time elapsed = " + str(t1-t0)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain your algorithm? I have a simple function here that generates such a radial profile, and it's also fast enough (11ms vs 28s for your function), but the results of your function do not match mine. If you can explain the algorithm, maybe I'll understand what you're doing.

Comment: Consider including your matlab code in the question, so that it is easier to see what is different.

Comment: I added an additional edit to the question.  I do find that the original (slow) code is also bugged.  I haven't tested the fast vectorized solution properly (against an analytic function) but it looks right by eye.